# Laravel Blade Helpers not pulling in columns with spaces

Tags: laravel

I have a table with many columns and some of those columns have spaces in their names (i.e. 'Provider First Name').  I know the syntax to use these in Blade helpers and am using this in other parts of my app: {`{$provider->{'Provider First Name'} }}`.  This works fine in other parts.

I have the following in my **ProviderController**:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $provider = NPIData::where('NPI', $id)->first();
    $providers = NPIData::all();

    return view ('profiles.provider', compact('provider', 'providers'));
}
```

I have brought in the NPIData Model to the controller.

I have the following in my **provide.blade.php** file:

```
    @extends('layouts.profiles')
    @section('content')

    <div>

    {{ $provider->NPI }}
    {{$provider->{'Provider First Name'} }}

    </div>
    @endsection
```

Oddly, the NPI will pull in, but the 'Provider First Name' does not.  I have tried many other columns with spaces and none of them work.  I even copied and pasted from other parts of my app where the syntax to pull these in works and it does not work here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
{{$provider->{'Provider First Name'} }}
```

Try this:

```
@php
   $providerFirstName = $provider->{'Provider First Name'};
@endphp
{{ $providerFirstName }}
```

#### UPDATE

If not you can always go with array access:

```
{{ $provider['Provider First Name'] }}
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.  Neither of those work for me.  Something strange must be going on somewhere.

Comment: Ahh, it was my fault.  A faulty record had been placed into the database that omitted the First Name.  Thanks for the help though.  I didn't know how to use the @php tags

Comment: dump the whole $proivder then and see if the column is even there

Comment: You can mark the answer accepted if it helped you so that we can close this thread on stackoverflow